# Making decisions based on find_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I am trying to do something like this (creating many files at once):

```
@files = params[:files].split(/\s*,\s*/) # comma-separated list is received
failures = []
@files.each do |file|
  unless File.find_or_create_by_name(:name => file, ...)
    failures << file
  end
end
if failures.present?
  errors.add(:base, "The following files are already in use: #{failures.to_sentence}
end
```

The above isn't quite working. When a file is 'found' rather than 'created', this is something that should prompt an error (i.e. because the file is NOT new). However, it is still not added to failures here (`find_or_create` never fails in this case).

How can I do the above in an elegant way?

Note: I want to avoid presenting users with an obnoxiously-large list of errors if, for example, they mistakenly try to create the same list of 100 files twice. I feel that simply listing the errors in a sentence would be better than displaying an individual error notice for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_or_create_by_name will always return the found or created record unless it failed because of a validation or something.

If adding validates_uniqueness_of :name doesn't work for you, consider this:

```
if File.find_by_name file
  failures << file
else
  unless File.create(:name => file, ...)
    failures << file
  end
end
```

But, if circumstances allow you to add a uniqueness validation, I would go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add `validates_uniqueness_of :name` to `File`? Then you could just do

```
unless File.create(:name => file, ...)
  failures << file
end
```